# Openupgrade from 6.1 to 7.0 issues with res.user model

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

Using openupgrade from openerp I found the issue with the database res.user because it can't located specific issues regardingt he model.

The error is thrown around three elements: context_lang context_tz and menu_tips

```
ERROR astro_migrated openerp.osv.orm: Can't find field 'context_tz' in the following view parts composing the view of object model 'res.users':
* res.users.form
Either you wrongly customized this view, or some modules bringing those views are not compatible with your current data model
```

Same goes for the other two fields.I am trying to investigate the migrated database and the content in but I see them the same.

Code on the migration script is a SQL sentence regarding the insert of the res.user data:

```
 for row in cr.fetchall():
    cr.execute(
        "INSERT INTO res_partner "
        "(name, active) "
        "VALUES(%s,%s) RETURNING id", row[1:])
    partner_id = cr.fetchone()[0]
    cr.execute(
        "UPDATE res_users "
        "SET partner_id = %s, "
        "openupgrade_7_created_partner_id = %s "
        "WHERE id = %s", (partner_id, partner_id, row[0]))
```